# Dropbox java api - can't use hebrew string

Tags: java, unicode, dropbox, dropbox-api, hebrew

I try to to create DbxEntry object with path that include hebrew character and it's doesn't work.
It's gives me "nullPointerException", Here is example of the code i try to run with main function:

```
public static void example(String s) throws IOException, DbxException{
    auth();
    DbxEntry a = client.getMetadata(s);
    System.out.println(a.name);
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, DbxException{
    System.out.println("First example: ");
    example("/Public");
    System.out.println("Working..");

    System.out.println("Second example: ");
    example("/לשום");
}
```

The output is:
First example: 
Linked account: Itay Velner
Public
Working..
Second example: 
Linked account: Itay Velner

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at node.Main.example(Main.java:137)
    at node.Main.main(Main.java:145)
```

I tried to look for help in the web and i doesn't find anything yet. if i convert the hebrew String into unicode it's still doesn't work.
I think that there is some problem with the api,

any thoughts?

Thanks,
Itay.

Comment: For reference, in case anyone else comes along this, this is fixed in version 1.7.7 of the Dropbox Java Core SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java

Comment: -1 for creating a duplicate of your own question